# Conversion of legacy outer join to ANSI

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have come across the following legacy PL/SQL and find the outer joins against scalar constants somewhat confusing.  First of all, can someone please confirm that my attempt to convert this to ANSI is correct.

**LEGACY CODE**:

```
cursor c1item (c1item_iel_id number) is  
select  
  `<columns>`  
from  iel_item iit, iel_item_property iip  
  where iit.iit_change_type = 'I'  
  and   iip.iip_change_type (+) = 'I'  
  and   iip.it_id (+)  = iit.it_id  
  and   iit.iel_id = c1item_iel_id  
  and   iip.iel_id (+) = c1item_iel_id;
```

**ANSI CODE**

```
cursor c1item (c1item_iel_id number) is  
select  
   `<columns>`  
from  iel_item iit  
left outer join iel_item_property iip  
on  iip.it_id = iit.it_id  
    and  iit.iit_change_type = 'I'  
    and  iip.iip_change_type = 'I'  
    and  iit.iel_id = c1item_iel_id  
    and  iip.iel_id = c1item_iel_id;
```

If this is correct, then I don't see the point of using an outer join.  Surely if the primary key **it_id** in table **iit** does not have a corresponding foreign key in table **iip** then both **iip.iit_change_type** and **iip.iel_id** will be NULL, in which case they will be filtered out by the AND clauses.  So why not just use an inner join?  Am I missing something? or is the original code nonsense?

Comment: Are you changing the legacy to ANSI or just getting a handle on what the ANSI would be?

Comment: Just trying to understand the legacy code.  Converting to ANSI seems to help.

Comment: But you're not going to change the code to the ANSI, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not correct -- only those marked with the "(+)" need to be in the LEFT JOIN, the rest are for the WHERE clause:

```
   SELECT `<columns>`  
     FROM iel_item iit  
LEFT JOIN iel_item_property iip  ON iip.it_id = iit.it_id  
                                AND iip.iip_change_type = 'I'  
                                AND iip.iel_id = c1item_iel_id
    WHERE iit.iit_change_type = 'I'      
      AND iit.iel_id = c1item_iel_id
```

Placement matters with OUTER JOINs -- criteria in the ON clause is applied before the JOIN, while criteria in the WHERE is applied **after** the JOIN.   This can greatly affect the result set returned, depends on data and setup.  Placement doesn't matter for INNER JOINS - in the WHERE or ON clause, the result set will be the same.

Comment: So I was missing something.  Thanks

Comment: @cyberwiki: I'm quite aware it's you downvoting my answer, and upvoting competing answers.  Doesn't matter that the answer is 100% correct, or before competing answers.  You can blame me for whatever downvotes you receive, doesn't mean I cast them though you do talk a lot of trash.  Get over yourself, and grow up already.

Comment: does it matter? Each dv is 0.003% of your score.

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't correct.  There were only 3 outer join predicates in the original query, your new one has all 5.

Should be:

```
cursor c1item (c1item_iel_id number) is  
select  
   `<columns>`  
from  iel_item iit  
left outer join iel_item_property iip  
on  iip.it_id = iit.it_id  
    and  iip.iip_change_type = 'I'  
    and  iip.iel_id = c1item_iel_id
where    and  iit.iel_id = c1item_iel_id  
    and  iit.iit_change_type = 'I' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be rewrited like this:

```
SELECT columns1
FROM   iel_item iit
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN iel_item_property iip
         ON iip.iip_change_type = 'I'
            AND iip.it_id = iit.it_id
            AND iip.iel_id = c1item_iel_id
WHERE  iit.iit_change_type = 'I'   
        AND iit.iel_id = c1item_iel_id
```

Next time, if you need to rewrite Oracle proprietary joins to ANSI SQL compliant joins, [here is a tool](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/rewrite-oracle-propriety-joins-to-ansi-sql-compliant-joins/) that can help you do it automatically with less error prone.